# Set template variable in form

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, variables

Is it possible to set pass a variable to a template from a form.

Eg in its simplest form something like this:

forms.py

```
class Form1(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Your email")
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name")
    message = forms.CharField(label="Body", widget=forms.Textarea)
    FORM_HEADER = "FOOO!"
```

views.py

```
def motor(request):
   return render(request, 'form.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': MotorQuoteRequestForm(),}))
```

and in form.html

```
...
{{ FORM_HEADER }}
<hr>
{% crispy form %}
....
```

So that you can create a neat little tag to import of the entire form package when you want to use it.

Help would be much appreciated :D

Comment: Also note that when you call `render` you do not need to explicitly create a `RequestContext` object. This is automatically created for you. See [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `{{ form.FORM_HEADER }}`?

Although it's probably simpler just to pass the header into the context as a separate variable.

Comment: form.FORM_HEADER is probably what I'm looking for, sorry for the stupid question, I'm a bit new to the flexible python programming.